# Object.assign() changes values of object even if object if frozen

Tags: javascript, node.js

I wanted to write some code that flattens the values of an object.
But I do not understand why the following code snipped changes the value of the original `data` !!!

```
let data = {'row1' : {'a11':10, 'a12':11},
            'row2' : {'a21':23, 'a22':11}}

let flat = Object.assign(...Object.values(data))

console.log('flat : ',flat)
console.log('data : ',data)
```

will result in

```
flat :  { a11: 10, a12: 11, a21: 23, a22: 11 }
data :  {
  row1: { a11: 10, a12: 11, a21: 23, a22: 11 },   <--- WHY!!!!!!!!!!!
  row2: { a21: 23, a22: 11 }
}
```

This even happenes if I freeze `data`,

```
let data = {'row1' : {'a11':10, 'a12':11},
            'row2' : {'a21':23, 'a22':11}}

data = Object.freeze(data)

let flat = Object.assign(...Object.values(data))

console.log('flat : ',flat)
console.log('data : ',data)
```

which also results in

```
flat :  { a11: 10, a12: 11, a21: 23, a22: 11 }
data :  {
  row1: { a11: 10, a12: 11, a21: 23, a22: 11 },   <--- WHY!!!!!!!!!!!
  row2: { a21: 23, a22: 11 }
}
```

What is going on?

Comment: `Object.freeze()` is shallow, not deep.

Comment: Because `Object.assign` assigns the properties on its first argument. You want `const newObj = Object.assign({}, ...Object.values(data));` (same as `const newObj = {}; Object.assign(newObj, ...Object.values(data));`.